# Titanium alloy create label with text when click on button

Tags: jquery, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am new to the titanium alloy and doing a thing 
  1] I am validating form in which after clicking submit button i want error message below to submit button and if it is validated then it should remove that message.

This functionality is possible in jquery but it is titanium alloy.
so please let me know if anybody have any idea to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible Titanium is JavaScript-based so you can build it yourself with javascript. There are also some modules available like this one:
http://haberdasheryjs.com/form-validation-module-for-titanium-mobile/ that would save you some time.